# Using ManagementObjectSearcher to query Win32_PnPEntity comes back empty

Tags: c#, wmi

OK, so this drives me nuts.

The code below worked just fine in Windows 7 with .NET 3.5.
In Windows 8.1 and .NET 4.5.1 I get an empty result, but using the WMI Code Creator I can get the results.

I cannot find anything about this online.

I want to get the friendly names of any COM ports, e.g. "Communications Port (COM1)".

Just using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` wont do.

I really hope someone know how to do this. Thanks!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

namespace OakHub
{
    public class SerialMgmt
    {
        static public List<String> GetCOMDevices()
        {
            List<String> list = new List<String>();

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\CIMV2");
            SelectQuery sq = new SelectQuery("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, sq);
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                String name = mo.ToString();
                if (name.ToString().Contains("(COM"))
                {
                    list.Add(name);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I dont know why this code is even working for you (with .Net 3.5).

1. You just selected the property `Caption`. (Use * to select all, if needed)
2. I think you want the name of the Win32_PnPEntity-Devices, you **cant** get it with this line of code

   `String name = mo.ToString();`

   Because the Name is a property. You First have to load the Property with the WMI-String :

   `SELECT Name,Caption FROM Win32_PnPEntity` //Get Name and Caption Property

   or

   `SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity` //Load all the Propertys of that WMI-Obj

And than you have to check if value is null else --> return the value

Code:

```
public List<String> GetLocalCOMDevices()
        {
            List<String> list = new List<String>();

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\CIMV2");
            SelectQuery sq = new SelectQuery("SELECT Name,Caption FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, sq);
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                object propName = mo.Properties["Name"].Value;
                if (propName == null) { continue; }

                list.Add(propName.ToString());
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Np. But I would do a IEnumerable<> Method. You know how to do that?

Comment: Nopes, it is on my todo-list. Unfortunately my new role gives me less time for coding.