# System.IO.Ports - Cannot see hidden serial-ports, how to enable in GetPortNames()?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I did not find any hidden devices, which are not part of the result list of GetPortNames().
Also there are no additional parameters for GetPortNames().

How to get the list of the existing, but with the hidden serial-ports?
(see screenshot, there are hidden entries)

Any hint appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
        // Print existing COM-Ports
        var comPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        Console.WriteLine("Detected COM-Ports:");
        if (comPorts.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - NONE -");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in comPorts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" - {item}");
            }
        }

        // new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'")    <<< always empty!
```

**RESULT:**

```
  Detected COM-Ports:
   - NONE -
```

[image: Hidden Serial Ports]

Comment: You might have some luck with a WMI query of some sort? Although I can't easily find one which claims to list hidden devices with a quick google

Comment: same to me... :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59822434/1205601  - I cannot use Powershell (it is not allowed in our company)

Comment: It looks like that uses [PnPEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity) (run `Get-Command Get-PnPEntity | fl *`), and looks like you might be able to query that [over WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29537661/1086121)?

Comment: It isn't obvious what is "hidden" about it.  But if it is hidden in Device Manager then it will be hidden to apps as well.  The USB device driver might still be loaded but no longer emulate a serial port.  Be sure to always, always use "Safely remove hardware" before you disconnect a port.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425 (see method _GetComPortInfo_) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425.  I've seen a computer show `COM1`, when nothing is attached. However, after refering to the motherboard documentation, the motherboard happened to have a COM port header which I believe is why a COM port showed up in device manager.